# there is a way to check how much ram is being used by a specific windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, ram

I need to know how much ram is used at that time by a windows service or program, but I don't know how to get there.

this makes me restart a service that I indicated on the service controller but I have to do it only if the ram exceeds a certain value that I have to indicate

```
     ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MSSQLSERVER");
        try
        {
            int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100000);

            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50000 - (millisec2 - millisec1));

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Errore");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: RAM is a performance optimization. The system will use as much as it can. The amount of RAM allotted to any given process by the system is usually not a useful metric.

Answer (score 0):

If you only know the process name, you can do

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").FirstOrDefault();
var memoryUsed = process?.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

Comment: process gives me null

Comment: Are you sure about the name? Do you have the needed permissions?

Comment: yes the name is right if you look at the code I use it for the stop and the start, as regards the permissions it is started as an administrator